# Android c2dm server simulator on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I am following android c2dm example from following link:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

I have implemented the client side successfully and have got my registration id. but i am having some issues in server end using the same example actually the issue is in getAuthentification method and i am getting following exception at HttpResponse response = client.execute(post).

java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com

Following is my code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email","you....@gmail.com"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd","*********"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", "GOOGLE"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source",
                "Google-cURL-Example"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "ac2dm"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("HttpResponse", line);
            if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
                Editor edit = prefManager.edit();
                edit.putString(AUTH, line.substring(5));
                edit.commit();
                String s = prefManager.getString(AUTH, "n/a");
                Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me? Your help would be highly appreciable. Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557996/android-httprequest-java-net-unknownhostexception

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue last week. When the C2DM servers return a 302 Moved (www.google.com) what they ACTUALLY mean is the authentication failed. The problem is almost certainly your authentication code, so re-check the code you're using to get the auth code from the ClientLogin API. Note that the HTTP response contains a bunch of information, not just the auth code, so you do need to parse it correctly (that was my mistake).

```
public static String getClientLoginAuthToken(String email, String password) {
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
try {

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", password));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", "GOOGLE"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source","Google-cURL-Example"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "ac2dm"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("Auth=")) {
        return line.substring(5);
    }
}
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get C2DM auth code");
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood your question. You're saying you're gettung an unknown host error, that would typically suggest your network connection has failed and the DNS lookup isn't working, but the fact you mention www.google.com makes me think you are actually getting a 302 redirect to that hostname. Try my code and see how you go.